# sqlite - how does contains work

Tags: android, sqlite

I am not overly experienced in SQL and now get a syntax error trying to invoke SQL from android:

```
 select _id from inAd where Name contains ?
```

says there is a Syntax error near contains.
However, it works fine if I use "=" instead of "contains".

Does anyone know what the issue is?w

Now following your advice, I tried:

```
        cursor = helper.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(
            "select _id from inAd where Name like ?",
            new String[] { str2 });
```

but to no avail.

Now also tried:

```
cursor = helper.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(
            "select _id from inAd where Name like ?",
            new String[] { "%<str2>%" });
```

Same Problem.

```
cursor = helper.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(
            "select _id from '"+inAd+" where Name like '%"+str2+"%'",
            null);
```

This time there is a syntax error near %.

Comment: What is the value of str2 when you run things?

Comment: %mystring%, where mystring is the content of the string

Comment: Maybe you can tell me something.  Why do so many newbies want to do a contains or like search?

Comment: I can tell you why I want to if you care, no idea about others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using LIKE, you must use wildcards at the beginning and end of the pattern:

```java
    cursor = helper.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(
        "select _id from inAd where Name like '%' || ? || '%'",
        new String[] { str2 });
```

or:

```java
    cursor = helper.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(
        "select _id from inAd where Name like ?",
        new String[] { "%" + str2 + "%" });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
select _id from inAd where Name like '%<Your String>%'
```

Comment: ? Maybe I should have specified, I am using a rawquery. I thought I HAVE to do the solution with the question mark then?

Answer (score 1):

'contains' is not a part of the SQL syntax. As @Kristy specified, you can use the LIKE operator or '='.

See if this works:

```
selectionArgs = new String[] { "%" + str2 + "%" };
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select _id from inAd where Name LIKE ?, selectionArgs);
```

Comment: Please post code when you are using LIKE. Also, is it the same error when you change to LIKE?

Comment: I already edited and posted the new code. And, actually, probably the last one is right, only now I tried to use a local variable for the table name and this backfires, but that is a different story

Comment: I should not have closed this question ----- still the same mistake